# Creating UWP app with Unity older versions

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp

We built an iPad app few years ago using Unity 5.2.1 where it loads 3d models using asset bundles and user can perform different actions on the model.
Now the client wants to build the same app to support Windows 10 tabs/desktops.

Since we have to use the same assetbundles already build, I will have to use the same Unity version. So I tried to build a Unity 5.2.1 sample to Windows store (Universal 10- xaml). But sometimes I am getting errors in Unity when trying to build that and sometimes it get build but when I try to run it in visual studio 2017 I get errors.

So I wasn't sure whether there is any limitation on building an app from Unity 5.2.1 for Visual studio 2017 for Uwp.
Does Unity 5.2.1 support creating a UWP app to run with Visual studio 2017 or are there any limitations on the Unity versions? 
Should I be able to do that work if I get the errors resolved?

Comment: All sources seem to agree, that you need Unity 5.3.2 or later for UWP, although sometimes getting errors, and sometimes not sounds more like a bug in your code.

Comment: Thanks @IInspecctable . Actually I was just trying with a sample unity project where a new scene was added and inserted a 3d object (cube) there. I didn't have any other code or anything else there.